# what does the ldapadd error: "additional info: objectClass: value #2invalid per syntax mean?

Tags: active-directory, ldap, database, openldap

I'am tryin to migrate from active directory windows server to Openldap i found a problem while importing .ldif database exported from AD to my new Openldap ! when  i try to do :
`ldapmodify -Y EXTERNAL  -H ldapi:/// -f exportuser.ldf`
i got :

```
dn:dc=si,dc=infra
changetype: add
objectClass: top
objectClass: domain
objectClass: domainDNS
distinguishedName: DC=si,DC=infra
instanceType: 5
whenCreated: 20140903112404.0Z
whenChanged: 20200710114957.0Z
subRefs: DC=ForestDnsZones,DC=si,DC=infra
subRefs: DC=DomainDnsZones,DC=si,DC=infra
subRefs: CN=Configuration,DC=si,DC=infra
uSNCreated: 4099
dSASignature:: AQAAACgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAFZdkFLMGb0aPv8u9xkFAiw==
repsFrom::
 AgAAAAAAAADwAQAAoQQAAEk0WhMDAAAArh8ZFQMAAADZBgAA2AAAABgBAABwAAAAERERERERERERER
 ERERERERERERERERERERERERERERERERERERERERERERERERERERERERERERERERERERERERERERER
 ERERERERERERERERERERAAAAAKpXAQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACqVwEAAAAAAK5eK8JSo2VLj8lZCMtB4q
 W2BWGS+bZXS5Ih2qP3nk/NAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAGAEAABgAAAAAAAAAkAAAAAAA
 AAAAAAAAYwAyADIAYgA1AGUAYQBlAC0AYQAzADUAMgAtADQAYgA2ADUALQA4AGYAYwA5AC0ANQA5AD
 AAOABjAGIANAAxAGUAMgBhADUALgBfAG0AcwBkAGMAcwAuAHMAaQBmAGEAcwB0AC4AaQBuAGYAcgBh
 AAAAAAAAAAAAYwAyADIAYgA1AGUAYQBlAC0AYQAzADUAMgAtADQAYgA2ADUALQA4AGYAYwA5AC0ANQ
 A5ADAAOABjAGIANAAxAGUAMgBhADUALgBfAG0AcwBkAGMAcwAuAHMAaQBmAGEAcwB0AC4AaQBuAGYA
 cgBhAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA==
repsFrom::
 AgAAAAAAAADwAQAAblMAAJkvBQ8DAAAAWh8ZFQMAAAC6BgAA2AAAABgBAABwAAAAERERERERERERER
 ERERERERERERERERERERERERERERERERERERERERERERERERERERERERERERERERERERERERERERER
 ERERERERERERERERERERAAAAALrDDAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAC6wwwAAAAAANGWjIQnKUVChkMTYKaH0u
 6nIrWbtxGPSZF02Z788HncAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAGAEAABgAAAAAAAAAkAAAAAAA
 AAAAAAAAOAA0ADgAYwA5ADYAZAAxAC0AMgA5ADIANwAtADQAMgA0ADUALQA4ADYANAAzAC0AMQAzAD
 YAMABhADYAOAA3AGQAMgBlAGUALgBfAG0AcwBkAGMAcwAuAHMAaQBmAGEAcwB0AC4AaQBuAGYAcgBh
 AAAAAAAAAAAAOAA0ADgAYwA5ADYAZAAxAC0AMgA5ADIANwAtADQAMgA0ADUALQA4ADYANAAzAC0AMQ
 AzADYAMABhADYAOAA3AGQAMgBlAGUALgBfAG0AcwBkAGMAcwAuAHMAaQBmAGEAcwB0AC4AaQBuAGYA
 cgBhAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA==
uSNChanged: 88191049
name: si
objectGUID:: L2ettnpuxEaavgfWpC5gUQ==
replUpToDateVector::
 AgAAAAAAAAACAAAAAAAAALYFYZL5tldLkiHao/eeT83zVwEAAAAAAEk0WhMDAAAApyK1m7cRj0mRdN
 me/PB53MzDDAAAAAAAiiEFDwMAAAA=
creationTime: 132388553973680553
forceLogoff: -9223372036854775808
```

Some help please .???

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to import an entry with an object class value not present in the subschema of your OpenLDAP server.

A migration from MS AD to OpenLDAP is not possible without importing much of MS AD schema. But even if you add the schema you would need other components really using that. In this particular case you would need a DNS server extracting DNS RRs from MS AD proprietary LDAP attributes.

A better alternative might be to migrate to Samba 4 in Active Directory mode which is supposed to be a drop-in replacement for MS AD.

Comment: so the best solution would be to Use DNS ? How ?

Why to migrate samba 4 and how ?

Comment: You should probably add more details to your question about what  you want to achieve and why, and what your system environment is.